# How to set the default value of the switch widget in android

Tags: android, xml

I am coding my xml file with the couple switch widgets. but I don't know how to set the default value of them as ON. And I just want to get this problem solved within the xml file so no Java.

Comment: what exactly "switch widget" mean to you?

Comment: @WebnetMobile.com http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Switch.html - new in ICS - [Screenshot here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/togglebutton.html)

Comment: please accept the answer if this helped. It helpful for future users.

Answer (score 127):

To make Switch set "ON" in you XML file use this:

```
android:checked="true"
```

Comment: Value is still false when I run my app when I include this in XML?

Answer (score 6):

To set the Switch default as ON  in XML file :

```
android:checked = "true"
```

Don't try using android:pressed = "true" . It will throw an error while running the app.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the Switch default as ON/OFF from the code itself. Try something like this:

```
    switch.setChecked(true) // to set it true
```

Or,

```
    switch.setChecked(false) // to set it false
```